# Crystal Reports for VS2019

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports

I have installed VS2019 on a fresh PC. I tried installing Crystal Reports, developer version for Microsoft Visual Studio `CRforVS_13_0_24` but it will not install, i get the error below
[image]

Is there a version for VS2019? or is there a way to get crystal reports working with VS2019?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your version of Crystal Reports (developer version) requires an earlier version of Visual Studio.

Visual Studio 2019 was not supported at the time of your question. With the release of SP25, which can be downloaded [here](https://www.crystalreports.com/crystal-reports-visual-studio/), that has changed.

Comment: My version of Visual Studio 2019 is 16.0.4

Comment: The issues are with Crystal Reports, not Visual Studio. SAP says SP25 will support Visual Studio 2019. In the meantime, you can use an earlier version of Visual Studio.

Comment: Do we have a release date for SP25?

Comment: It has been released and Visual Studio 2019 is now supported.

Comment: @R.J.Dunnill I can't see a download link on the official website, could you please share? Thanks.

Comment: Did you register? Registration appears to be required.

Comment: you can now download it here https://www.crystalreports.com/crystal-reports-visual-studio/

Comment: Which leads to the same link I posted. One cannot access the download without registering.

Answer (score 4):

The direct link to download Visual Studio 2019

http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_13_0_25.exe

Copied from

[Download Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2019](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/crystal-reports/download-crystal-reports-for-visual-studio-2019/)