# Can we create a new Crystal Report version 13.0.19 in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I have Visual Studio 2019. I developed a SAP Crystal Report in version 13.0.3500.0. But my project has many SAP Crystal Reports using version 13.0.19.

On my machine, I have installed from [image]

But on the server, I have installed SAP Crystal Reports version 13.0.19 runtime only.

I want to use SAP Crystal Report version 13.0.19 in Visual Studio 2019.
Do have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install the latest (sp 31) one from the below link which supports the earlier version too. It might be overwriting the existing version (see similar issue:- [Crystal Reports for VS2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56160786/crystal-reports-for-vs2019))

https://www.tektutorialshub.com/crystal-reports/download-crystal-reports-for-visual-studio-2019/

or

https://www.crystalreports.com/download/

How to choose that you can check via prerequisites requirements:
https://www.tektutorialshub.com/crystal-reports/download-crystal-reports-for-visual-studio-2019/#direct-download-link

Comment: Thanks for the answer to me. But on the production server has used **13.0.19** runtime only.  Also, assembly is used **13.0.2000.0**
When I used **13.0.19** in my machine with **Developer Edition Download**  **SP25**, then their assembly is used **13.0.3500.0**

Comment: please check this link - https://answers.sap.com/questions/13044479/difference-between-crystal-report-run-time-version.html

Comment: are you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56160786/crystal-reports-for-vs2019?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I have checked but it is not the same thing as I mentioned in my description and first comment. :(